# How to split instances in a custom object based on if there are multiple values in an array?

Tags: powershell

To start off, I am sorry if my terminology is not accurate in the title.

So basically I have created a custom object in a foreach loop that I want to change a bit. 
Here is an example:

```
$Report = [PSCustomObject]@{
"Name" = $obj1.Name
"Description" = $obj2.Desc 
"Mail" = $obj2.Mail}
$AllReports += $Report
```

When I run the AllReports I get this:

```
Name          : {Name1, Name2, Name3}
Description   : Desc
Mail          : Mail
```

(The number of names in the array go from 1 to many)

But I want this:

```
Name          : Name1
Description   : Desc
Mail          : Mail

Name          : Name2
Description   : Desc
Mail          : Mail

Name          : Name3
Description   : Desc
Mail          : Mail
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need in extra loop when initially creating the custom objects. Can you show the full loop that creates the objects? Including how you created/populated `$obj1`

Comment: Let me continue with the example names even though it may sound weird. First I find all the [Mail] then I pipe them to foreach-object loop where I use Search-UnifiedAuditLog to identify Name. The issue is the many [Name] can have the same [Mail]

Comment: Please post the actual code (or code that reproduces the issue) :)

Comment: I have no idea what just happened but a restart of my powershell ISE and a simple change of variable name for some reason solved the problem more or less by itself. I will close the ticket. Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The original solution worked all of a sudden.

Simplified:

```
Mail | foreach { $name = search-unifiedauditlog -objectids $_.name

foreach ($row in $name) {
$Report = [PSCustomObject]@{
"Name" = $name.Name
"Description" = $mail.Desc 
"Mail" = $mail.Mail}
$AllReports += $Report
}
}
```